# Utilizing BorderLayout on JFrame. ( Using Container)

Tags: java, swing

New to GUI, I am trying to create a simple JFrame with two JTextAreas positioned right next to each other and a JPanel at the bottom.

```
public class Demo extends JFrame
{
    JPanel panel; 
    JTextArea JTextArea1; 
    JTextArea JTextArea2; 
    DecisionPanel decisionPanel; 

    public Demo()
    { 
        super( "Black Jack Server" ); 

        JFrame f = new JFrame(); 
        f.setSize( 400, 400 ); ;
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE ); 
        f.setVisible( true ); 

        DecisionPanel decisionPanel = new DecisionPanel(); 
        f.getContentPane().add( decisionPanel ); 

        JTextArea1 = new JTextArea(); 
        add( JTextArea1); 

        JTextArea2 = new JTextArea(); 
        add( JTextArea2 );  
    }
}
```

Do I use BorderLayout to get the result that I want? If so, how should I approach?

Answer (score 3):

You could nest JPanels and...

- place the `JTextAreas` in their own `JScrollPanes`,
- place the `JScrollPanes` into a `GridLayout(1, 2)` (1 row, two columns) using `JPanel`
- place that `JPanel` into a `BorderLayout` using `JPanel` in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position
- and place your bottom `JPanel` in the `BorderLayout.PAGE_END` position.

  ---

Something like:

[image]

Comment: is this how you add JTextAreas to GridLayout?:


                JTextArea1 = new JTextArea(); 
  add( new JScrollPane( JTextArea1 ) ); 
  
  JTextArea2 = new JTextArea(); 
  add( new JScrollPane( JTextArea2 ) );
  
  JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
                gridLayout = new GridLayout( 1, 2, 5, 5 );
  gridLayout.add( JTextArea1, JTextArea2 );
                panel.add( gridLayout );

Comment: @GTA No, `GridLayout` is a layout manager, use `setLayout` instead.  Then simply add you components to the container like normal.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details